# How to get all product details using REST API in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have created Integration in System->Integration. And Set access to catelog ->products to the integration. I can get Single Product by Sku using

> http://localhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/:sku

But i need to display all the products. How to get the result.

Thanks in advance.

My Code to get product details

```
function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
{
    $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);

    $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
    $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);

    $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
}

function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
{
    $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
    $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}

// REPLACE WITH YOUR ACTUAL DATA OBTAINED WHILE CREATING NEW INTEGRATION
$consumerKey = 'key';
$consumerSecret = 'key';
$accessToken = 'key';
$accessTokenSecret = 'key';

$method = 'GET';
$url = 'http://localhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/products';

//
$data = [
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
];

$data['oauth_signature'] = sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
    ]
]);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo '<pre>';print_r(json_decode($result));
```

But it returns error

```
[message] => %fieldName is a required field.
    [parameters] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fieldName] => searchCriteria
        )
```

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you've any query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get admin token,

```
$adminUrl='http:Yourlurl/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => "admin_username", "password" => "admin_password");
$dataString = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataString))
);
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token = json_decode($token);
print_r($token);
curl_close($ch);
```

You can make use of below code, If you have many products increase the page_size.

```
<?php
$productUrl='http:yourlUrl/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=20';

$ch = curl_init($productUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer $token"
    )
);
$productList = curl_exec($ch);
$err      = curl_error($ch);
$products = json_decode($productList);
echo '<pre>';print_r($products );
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: can you tell me plz where to put this code in my module directory??

Comment: You can use this code anywhere, for convenient you can use in Model

Comment: can you give me specific directory for this, i cant understand this?

Comment: Could you explain your requirement ?

Comment: i want to create administrator hardcoded on back-end, through which i want to access all the resources of the administator, till know i generated the token through which i want to access all the resources, any help from you should appreciated, thanks:)

Comment: @aravind My api key : https://snipboard.io/oN3HiP.jpg postman : https://snipboard.io/ncOurb.jpg getting error, any help thanks

Answer (score 4):

In order to display all products, you need to have at least one criteria sent to the  Rest endpoint. If you have more than 1000 items, you could loop through the pages (although any example with > 1000 items would require more work to deal with that amount of data).

Note: you will need to install the zend http composer package as below:
`composer require zendframework/zend-http`

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$customer_access_token = 'uvreguaelo0tug3tqmfx633420e3pth3';

$httpHeaders = new Zend\Http\Headers();
$httpHeaders->addHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $customer_access_token,
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
]);

$request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
$request->setHeaders($httpHeaders);
$request->setUri('http://magento.test/rest/V1/products?fields=items[sku,name]&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1000');

$client = new Zend\Http\Client();

$response = $client->send($request);
$products = json_decode($response->getBody());

foreach ($products->items as $key => $product) {
    printf("Product SKU: %s, product name: %s\n", $product->sku, $product->name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using **[catalogProductRepositoryV1](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#!/catalogProductRepositoryV1)**

- method `GET`
- Authentication `admin token`
- **url**: `http://localhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/products`

**Response**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "sku": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "attributeSetId": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "status": 0,
      "visibility": 0,
      "typeId": "string",
      "createdAt": "string",
      "updatedAt": "string",
      "weight": 0,
      "extensionAttributes": {
        "downloadableProductLinks": [
          {
            "id": 0,
            "title": "string",
            "sortOrder": 0,
            "isShareable": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "numberOfDownloads": 0,
            "linkType": "string",
            "linkFile": "string",
            "linkFileContent": {
              "fileData": "string",
              "name": "string",
              "extensionAttributes": {}
            },
            "linkUrl": "string",
            "sampleType": "string",
            "sampleFile": "string",
            "sampleFileContent": {
              "fileData": "string",
              "name": "string",
              "extensionAttributes": {}
            },
            "sampleUrl": "string",
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ],
        "downloadableProductSamples": [
          {
            "id": 0,
            "title": "string",
            "sortOrder": 0,
            "sampleType": "string",
            "sampleFile": "string",
            "sampleFileContent": {
              "fileData": "string",
              "name": "string",
              "extensionAttributes": {}
            },
            "sampleUrl": "string",
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ],
        "stockItem": {
          "itemId": 0,
          "productId": 0,
          "stockId": 0,
          "qty": 0,
          "isInStock": true,
          "isQtyDecimal": true,
          "showDefaultNotificationMessage": true,
          "useConfigMinQty": true,
          "minQty": 0,
          "useConfigMinSaleQty": 0,
          "minSaleQty": 0,
          "useConfigMaxSaleQty": true,
          "maxSaleQty": 0,
          "useConfigBackorders": true,
          "backorders": 0,
          "useConfigNotifyStockQty": true,
          "notifyStockQty": 0,
          "useConfigQtyIncrements": true,
          "qtyIncrements": 0,
          "useConfigEnableQtyInc": true,
          "enableQtyIncrements": true,
          "useConfigManageStock": true,
          "manageStock": true,
          "lowStockDate": "string",
          "isDecimalDivided": true,
          "stockStatusChangedAuto": 0,
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        },
        "giftcardAmounts": [
          {
            "websiteId": 0,
            "value": 0,
            "websiteValue": 0,
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ],
        "configurableProductOptions": [
          {
            "id": 0,
            "attributeId": "string",
            "label": "string",
            "position": 0,
            "isUseDefault": true,
            "values": [
              {
                "valueIndex": 0,
                "extensionAttributes": {}
              }
            ],
            "extensionAttributes": {},
            "productId": 0
          }
        ],
        "configurableProductLinks": [
          0
        ],
        "bundleProductOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": 0,
            "title": "string",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "position": 0,
            "sku": "string",
            "productLinks": [
              {
                "id": "string",
                "sku": "string",
                "optionId": 0,
                "qty": 0,
                "position": 0,
                "isDefault": true,
                "price": 0,
                "priceType": 0,
                "canChangeQuantity": 0,
                "extensionAttributes": {}
              }
            ],
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ]
      },
      "productLinks": [
        {
          "sku": "string",
          "linkType": "string",
          "linkedProductSku": "string",
          "linkedProductType": "string",
          "position": 0,
          "extensionAttributes": {
            "qty": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "productSku": "string",
          "optionId": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "type": "string",
          "sortOrder": 0,
          "isRequire": true,
          "price": 0,
          "priceType": "string",
          "sku": "string",
          "fileExtension": "string",
          "maxCharacters": 0,
          "imageSizeX": 0,
          "imageSizeY": 0,
          "values": [
            {
              "title": "string",
              "sortOrder": 0,
              "price": 0,
              "priceType": "string",
              "sku": "string",
              "optionTypeId": 0
            }
          ],
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "mediaGalleryEntries": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "mediaType": "string",
          "label": "string",
          "position": 0,
          "disabled": true,
          "types": [
            "string"
          ],
          "file": "string",
          "content": {
            "base64EncodedData": "string",
            "type": "string",
            "name": "string"
          },
          "extensionAttributes": {
            "videoContent": {
              "mediaType": "string",
              "videoProvider": "string",
              "videoUrl": "string",
              "videoTitle": "string",
              "videoDescription": "string",
              "videoMetadata": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "tierPrices": [
        {
          "customerGroupId": 0,
          "qty": 0,
          "value": 0,
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "customAttributes": [
        {
          "attributeCode": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "searchCriteria": {
    "filterGroups": [
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "field": "string",
            "value": "string",
            "conditionType": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "sortOrders": [
      {
        "field": "string",
        "direction": "string"
      }
    ],
    "pageSize": 0,
    "currentPage": 0
  },
  "totalCount": 0
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get product details in core php .... Is there any example for this?

Comment: Please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add searchCriteria field name at the end of your url as follows:

```
$url = 'http://localhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria';
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027380/magento-2-rest-api-get-all-product) link for your reference. It may helpful to you.